# Flutter: How do I prevent weird navigation in the case of showing HomePage only when user is verified through email?

Tags: firebase, flutter, state-management, flutter-state

Intended Flow: Only show the home page when the user verifies their email.
What is actually happening: The user can pop the navigation stack to show the home page.

I'm using Firebase to handle my authentication flow and currently am using a StreamBuilder to show either the landing page or the home page at the root of the app depending on if a user is verified and not null.

```
//create user object based on Firebase User
  UserApp _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? UserApp(uid: user.uid, isVerified: user.emailVerified):null;
  }

//userapp type class
class UserApp {
  final String uid;
  final bool isVerified;
  UserApp({this.isVerified, this.uid});
}
```

Then I have a StreamBuilder that lives on top of my main.dart file:

```
class AuthWidgetBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthWidgetBuilder({Key key, @required this.builder}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<UserApp>) builder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder<UserApp>(
        stream: authService.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final UserApp user = snapshot.data;
          //only show home page if user is non null and also if they verified their email.
          if (user != null && authService.currentUser().isVerified == true) {
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                Provider<UserApp>.value(value: user),
              ],
              child: builder(context, snapshot),
            );
          }
          return builder(context, snapshot);
        });
  }
}

class AuthWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthWidget({Key key, @required this.userSnapshot}) : super(key: key);
  final AsyncSnapshot<UserApp> userSnapshot;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      return userSnapshot.hasData ? HomePage() : LandingPage();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then this is my main.dart file with the StreamBuilder and AuthService class on top of the widget tree:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<AuthService>(
        create: (_) => AuthService(),
        child: AuthWidgetBuilder(builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: AuthWidget(userSnapshot: userSnapshot),
          );
        }));
  }
```

How come I can pop the navigation stack to reveal the home page, even when I have not yet verified the user through email? What do I need to change in my code to make sure that the user can only see the home page, after verifying their email? Is there any resource I can look at to understand these concepts better?

Comment: I think u should seperate ur screens(Splash/Login/Home). The app first show only the splash screen then check if the user is verified or not. if he's verified navigate to home_screen if not navigate to login_screen.

Comment: Right, that's currently what I'm doing. I have a (Splash/Login/SignUp/CompleteSignUp/Home) screen. After sign up page, it goes to complete sign up page, where once user submits it sends a verification email. However, if I click the back button and pop the navigation stack, even without user clicking on verification link, it will route to the home page because of the conditional on the StreamBuilder. I'm trying to understand why it's doing that.

Comment: I think u need to clear all the navigation stack before navigating to a new route `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()`.

Comment: Even I remove the navigation stack, it will still show the home page even with user is not verified. So I'm guessing there is something off by the conditionals im using in the StreamBuilder.